# JavaScript and the DOM Manipulation (Creating and Deleting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I'm trying to to basically dynamically create li's inside an array, and I would like to create a 'delete' button within each li, so that when I click that li, I can delete that specific li.

I know this seems very basic, but I've been looking at JS for hours now, and am starting to really confuse myself here.
I keep getting errors like addChild() is not a function... I feel like I'm close, but no cigar. Thanks in advance!

Anyway, here's my add function:

```
function add(){
    var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
    deleteBtn.type = 'submit';
    deleteBtn.name = 'addButton';
    deleteBtn.className = 'deleteButton';

    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        id_number[i] = i+1;

        var newSong = '<li class="li_test" id="' + id_number[i] + '">' + "<span>" + "</span>" + '</li>';
        // $(newSong).appendChild(deleteBtn);
        $(deleteBtn).appendTo("#playlist-1");
        $(newSong).appendTo("#playlist-1");
        showList.push(newSong);

        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            deleteFromPlaylist(newSong);
        });
    }
 }
```

Here's my delete function

```
function deleteFromPlaylist(newSong){
    var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByTagName('deleteButton');
    // var deleteMe = deleteBtn.parentNode;
    alert(deleteBtn);
    for(i=0;i<showList.length;i++){
        if(newSong === showList[i]){
            showList.splice(i,1);
            // var pp = p.parentNode;

            // pp.removeChild (p);
            deleteMe = deleteMe.parentNode.remove("li_test");
            deleteMe.removeChild(deleteBtn);
        }
    // console.log(deleteMe);
      }
    }
```

**EDIT: 1 More Related Question**

I would like to only add an item if it doesn't exist already in the array. Here is what I have so far. Any tips on where I'm going wrong?

```
for (i = 0; i < showList.length; i++) {

    if (newSong !== showList[i]){
        ul_list.innerHTML = newSong;
        container_div.appendChild(ul_list); //append the info
        container_div.appendChild(deleteBtn);

        document.getElementById('playlist-1').appendChild(container_div); //finally add it to the playlist div

        showList.push(newSong);

        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            deleteFromPlaylist(evt, newSong);
        });
        inc++;
        alert("It IS in the Array!");
    }else{
        alert("This already exists!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'll start off with the simplest things..  There is no `<deleteButton>` tag.  Also, are you using jquery in this?  It isn't clear because you haven't said so or tagged your question as such.  It could be a custom function for all I know.

Comment: Ah. Whoops. You are correct, I think I meant to use getElementsByClassName. Also, my errors are now all stemming from: deleteMe = deleteMe.parentNode.remove("li_test");

Comment: And yes I'm using a slight amount of jQuery, which is what I'm more used to, but I eventually want to write it all in plain vanilla JS.

Comment: Your mixture of jQuery/non-query is one of the sources of your problem. For example, `deleteMe.parentNode.remove()` won't work because `parentNode` is not a jQuery object, but rather a plain DOMNode.  That should be `deleteMe.parent().remove()`  _or_ the plain JS version `deleteMe.parentNode.removeChild()`

Comment: Why would you want to convert a smattering of jQuery into Javascript? Leverage the power of jQuery!

Comment: I'm trying to become better at vanilla JS. sometimes jQuery feels magical and if I'm trying to eventually get a job using this, I would like to have a much stronger understanding of what's going on. I've worked with it before, but I think my knowledge of jQuery and JS are geting muddied together as @MichaelBerkowski said. Also, Michael, thanks for your response! I tried that, and I'm getting the error "TypeError: deleteMe.parentNode is undefined", which seems to be a similar error that I've seen a lot of tonight.

Comment: @eightonrose I do see that you have the `var deleteMe` line commented out, so it is undefined when that other call happens.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks. I just noticed that, but now I'm back to my original problem. When I uncomment that, I get: TypeError: deleteBtn.parentNode is not a function for that line. It's times like these where I get a little frustrated.

Comment: @eightonrose That's because of what was mentioned earlier - there's no tag name `deleteButton`, so `getElementsByTagName` can't return anything of the sort. If you're targeting the `<input>` you created for deleteButton, give it an id on creation and use `getElementById()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered your code and functions to purely use javascript, instead of a mixture containg jquery.  I've added comments in the code to explain my actions.  If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
var showList = [];
var inc = 1;

function add() {
    //create the container element.  If we do this, keeping track of all elements
    //becomes easier, since we just have to remove the container.
    var container_div = document.createElement('div');
    container_div.id = "cont_" + inc;

    var ul_list = document.createElement('ul');

    var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
    deleteBtn.type = 'button';
    deleteBtn.value = 'remove song';
    deleteBtn.name = 'addButton';
    deleteBtn.className = 'deleteButton';

    var id_number = [];
    var newSong = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        id_number[i] = i + 1;

        newSong += '<li class="li_test" id="cont_' + inc + '_song_id_' + id_number[i] + '">' + "<span>test " + inc + "</span>" + '</li>\n'; //all ids must be unique, so we construct it here
    }

    ul_list.innerHTML = newSong;
    container_div.appendChild(ul_list); //append the info
    container_div.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    document.getElementById('playlist-1').appendChild(container_div); //finally add it to the playlist div

    showList.push(newSong);

    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        deleteFromPlaylist(evt, newSong);
    });
    inc++;
}

function deleteFromPlaylist(evt, newSong) {
    var deleteBtn = evt.target; //target the button clicked, instead of a list of all buttons
    var container_div = deleteBtn.parentNode; //get the parent div of the button
    var cont_parent = container_div.parentNode; //and the parent of the container div
    for (i = 0; i < showList.length; i++) {
        if (newSong === showList[i]) {
            showList.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    cont_parent.removeChild(container_div); //finally, remove the container from the parent
}
```

**Update:**
I've modified the above function to strictly use objects, rather than strings, because it is easier to extract relevant information from objects, than strings.

I've added in comments to assist with understanding the code.  Again, if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
function add() {
    var list_bool;
    //create the container element.  If we do this, keeping track of all elements
    //becomes easier, since we just have to remove the container.
    var container_div = document.createElement('div');
    container_div.id = "cont_" + inc;

    var ul_list = document.createElement('ul');

    var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
    deleteBtn.type = 'button';
    deleteBtn.value = 'remove song';
    deleteBtn.name = 'addButton';
    deleteBtn.className = 'deleteButton';

    var list_item = document.createElement("li"); //create list element
    list_item.className = "li_test"; //set element class
    var list_span = document.createElement("span"); //create span element
    list_span.innerHTML = "test"; //set span text
    list_item.appendChild(list_span); //append span to list element

    ul_list.appendChild(list_item); //append list element to un-ordered list element
    var list_bool = false; //create local boolean variable
    if (showList.length > 0) { // loop through showList if it isn't empty
        for (var i = 0; i < showList.length; i++) {
            if (showList[i].innerText !== list_item.innerText) {
                list_bool = true; //if song exists(comparing text values, set bool to true
            } else if (showList[i].innerText === list_item.innerText) {
                list_bool = false; //else, set it to false
                break; //break out of loop.. we don't want it becoming true again, now do we?
            }
        }
    } else {
        list_bool = true; //showList is empty, set to true
    }
    if (list_bool) { //if true, do action of appending to list
        container_div.appendChild(ul_list); //append the info
        container_div.appendChild(deleteBtn);

        document.getElementById('playlist-1').appendChild(container_div); //finally add it to the playlist div
        showList.push(list_item);
        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            deleteFromPlaylist(evt, newSong);
        });
        inc++;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjpsa/3/), notice that `add()` is executed twice, but because the song 'test' already exists, it only executes the end action once.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. I really appreciate the comments you left in because it cleared up where I was getting confused. I seriously appreciate it.

Comment: I do have a question related to my array however. I would only like to add the container_div to the ul_list and push the newSong to showList if and only if that item does not already exist in the array already. If it does exist, I would like to console.log("This already exists!" so that I don't get any duplicates in my array. I'm currently throwing a for loop and then an if statement, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated my code up top to reflect what I tried and hopefully try to get across what I'm going for

Comment: @eightonrose Do you need to refer at all to the specific songs at any point in your code?  If not, you can remove the id attribute from your song generation code, because currently that's throwing everything off.

Comment: You're correct. I think I can get rid of the id's. Why would that be throwing it off though? I'm checking to see if newSong !== songList[i]... Isn't the string value what counts?

Comment: @eightonrose <strike>Because ids must be unique.  As you're comparing string values, and each id is unique.. it's always going to not be equal.</strike> A moment while I review again, I thought that ids were apart of the string.  If they are not, well.

Comment: The string is in the span. The id's are in the tags and shouldn't be affecting that. Eventually I'm going to have playlist1 be dynamic, and give myself the option to create new playlists (new arrays). It's going to get crazy, but one thing at a time. I think I'm going to start commenting out what I need to do in English or at least come up with an attack plan before I dive right in next time.

Comment: Unless, maybe I should be checking for the id number in the if statement? That's my problem with JS. I know there are several ways to do the same thing, but doing things the right way is a different story.

Comment: @eightonrose Will you always need to loop to add songs?  It just seems unnecessary since you only do it one time.  If you got rid of that it would simplify things.

Comment: I will be using AJAX/JSON to pull in data, and each time a new song is loaded, it will reflect that data, but I think you're right. the looping once might be a little excessive. Might as well just have each new item created as a singular call.

Comment: With all of that commented out, still running into problems

Comment: @eightonrose I'm working on it.  I'll comment here/update my answer when I have a working solution.

Comment: Sorry, I've been traveling all day. Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of making them as objects instead of strings. Understanding the syntax is one thing, but knowing what to do with it is another. All part of the learning process I suppose

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a strange mix of code. Forget the jQuery stuff until you know javascript.

```
> function add(){
>     var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
>     deleteBtn.type = 'submit';
```

I don't think that's a good idea. Much better to use type button or a button element.

```
>     deleteBtn.name = 'addButton';
>     deleteBtn.className = 'deleteButton';
> 
>     for(i=0;i<1;i++){
```

Presumably `i` will go a bit higher in future. ;-)

```
>         id_number[i] = i+1;
```

Where did `id_number` come from?

```
> 
>         var newSong = '<li class="li_test" id="' + id_number[i] + '">' + "<span>" + "</span>" + '</li>';
>         // $(newSong).appendChild(deleteBtn);
```

Stick to one method of creating elements. Consider using a document fragment to hold the parts.

```
>         $(deleteBtn).appendTo("#playlist-1");
>         $(newSong).appendTo("#playlist-1");
>         showList.push(newSong);
```

Where did `showList` come from?

```
>         deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

>             deleteFromPlaylist(newSong);
>         });
```

Not all browsers support `addEventListener`. Since you are only adding one listener, consider just assigning to the button's `onclick` property. Note that `newSong` is just a string.

```
>     }
>  }
```

In the other function:

```
> function deleteFromPlaylist(newSong){
>     var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByTagName('deleteButton');
```

There is no HTML "deleteButton" element, so that will return an empty collection.

```
>     // var deleteMe = deleteBtn.parentNode;
>     alert(deleteBtn);
>     for(i=0;i<showList.length;i++){
>         if(newSong === showList[i]){
>             showList.splice(i,1);
>             // var pp = p.parentNode;
> 
>             // pp.removeChild (p);
>             deleteMe = deleteMe.parentNode.remove("li_test");
```

Where did `deleteMe` come from? You commented out where it was declared and it hasn't been assigned a value, so `deleteMe.parentNode` will throw an error.

```
>             deleteMe.removeChild(deleteBtn);
>         }
>     // console.log(deleteMe);
>       }
>     }
> }
```

Anyhow, here's some working code, it's still pretty awful but I'll leave it to you go improve it.

```
<script>

var showList = [];

function add(){
    var id_number = [];
    var deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
    deleteBtn.type = 'button';
    deleteBtn.name = 'addButton';
    deleteBtn.className = 'deleteButton';
    deleteBtn.value = 'Delete Button';

    for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
        id_number[i] = i + 1;

        // '<li class="li_test" id="' + id_number[i] + '">' + "<span>" + "</span>" + '</li>';
        var newSong = document.createElement('li');
        newSong.className = 'li_test';
        newSong.id = id_number[i];
        newSong.appendChild(document.createElement('span').appendChild(document.createTextNode('song')));
        showList.push(newSong);
        deleteBtn.onclick = (function(id) {
                               return function(){deleteFromPlaylist(id);}
                            }(newSong.id));
        newSong.appendChild(deleteBtn);
        document.getElementById('playlist-1').appendChild(newSong);
    }
}

function deleteFromPlaylist(id) {
    var song = document.getElementById(id);
    if (song) {
        song.parentNode.removeChild(song);
    }
} 

window.onload = function() {
  add();
}

</script>

<ul id="playlist-1">
  <li>Original
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution was just as helpful. Thanks! I appreciate all the explanations, and yes I know I was getting really tangled up, so thats why it was starting to make little sense by the end there o.O